# How to check the HTTP header value before entering a controller using an attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, attributes, custom-attributes

I am trying to check if the http header contains a specific value and then perform some operations on it. I could write a method for this but I was wondering if I could do this using an attribute. Something like:

```
[CheckHeader("SomeValue")]
public IHttpActionResult MyController()
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Also, is there a way I could prevent the controller from being run depending on the header value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could derive from `AuthorizeAttribute` and return `true` or `false` based on the value in the header

```
public class CheckHeader: AuthorizeAttribute
{
  private readonly string _Value;
  public CheckHeader(string value)
  {
    _Value = value;
  }
  protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
  {
    // Get the headers
    var headers = httpContext.Request.Headers;
    // Do some checks (not sure what your wanting to do)
    if (headers["SomeHeader"] == _Value)
    {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this. I am getting an error saying no suitable method for override

Comment: Then why did your accept it? :) Give me 30 minutes then I'll create a test project and test it out and let you know.

Comment: Oops - should be `protected override bool ...` (not `public`) Note also because this is an `AuthorizeAttribute` it will redirect you back to the login page if you return `false` - I'm not really sure what you want do do so its just an example of what you can do.